# Problems with closing a menu with onclick and eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with closing a menu when using an mouseup event.
I want the menu to close when you click outside the menu which drops down, that works fine. But when I click the list element itself, the menu doesnt disappear once it has been opened. I want the menu to disappear both when u click outside the element, and when u click on the list item.

code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6132jg9m/2/

```
    var dropDownContent = document.querySelector(".drop-down-content");
    var dropDownTrigger = document.querySelector(".drop-down");

    dropDownTrigger.onclick = function () {
        dropDownTrigger.classList.toggle("active");

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', clickedOutside);
    };

    function clickedOutside(e) {
        if (e.target != dropDownContent &&
            e.target.parentNode != dropDownContent) {
            dropDownTrigger.classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the menu a list of links that jump to other locations? If so it doesn't matter if the menu closes when you click a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

> *"Thx for the answer. This does work, but the only thing is that when u click inside of the drop down menu, the menu closes. Any possible way around this?"*

As per OP's request, the demo has been modified as follows:

- The first `<a>`nchor of `.drop-down` is assigned `.trigger`
- Added a condition that whenever `.trigger` is clicked (`e.target`), it will toggle `.active` on menu.

---

## `.contains()`

Use [`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to reference `.drop-down` descendant tags and determine if any of them were clicked ([`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)).

---

### Demo

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/9tmn5pq2/)

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Register click event on document
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // Reference the menu (ddn = .drop-down)
  var ddn = document.querySelector('.drop-down');

  /*
  Check if any tag nested in menu (ddn.contains)
  was clicked (e.target)
  */
  var trg = ddn.contains(e.target);

  // if the clicked tag was .trigger...
  if (e.target.matches('.trigger')) {

    // ...toggle .active on menu
    ddn.classList.toggle('active');

    /*
    But if the clicked tag was nested within the menu and the
    menu isn't .active...
    */
  } else if (trg && !ddn.matches('.active')) {

    // ...add the class .active on menu.
    ddn.classList.add('active');

    // Stop event bubbling so it doesn't trigger the ancestor tags
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Or if any descendant tags were clicked and the menu was .active...
  } else if (trg && ddn.matches('.active')) {

    // ...just stop event bubbling 
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Otherwise if it was an ancestor tag of menu...
  } else if (!trg) {

    // ...remove .active from menu
    ddn.classList.remove('active');

  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

nav>span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #3ab4a6;
}

ul::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a:hover,
.drop-down:hover {
  background: #49505a;
}

.drop-down {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-down.active {
  background: #49505a;
}

.drop-down.active>.drop-down-content {
  display: block;
}

.drop-down.active>a>#arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.drop-down-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 250px;
  background: #49505a;
}

#arrow {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.drop-down-content a:hover {
  background: #2f343b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Drop-down-menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="drop-down-menu.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li class="drop-down"><a class='trigger'>More <span id="arrow" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="drop-down-content">
          <li><a>Drop down1</a></li>
          <li><a>Drop down2</a></li>
          <li><a>Drop down3</a></li>
          <li><a>Drop down4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. This does work, but the only thing is that when u click inside of the drop down menu, the menu closes. Any possible way around this?

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't multiply event listening inside the first click event. Secondly, you must condition the document click event to be executed when not hovering the menu element.

Here is your script a bit modified with "matches" method:

```
    var dropDownTrigger = document.querySelector(".drop-down");

    dropDownTrigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
        dropDownTrigger.classList.toggle("active");
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        if (!dropDownTrigger.matches(':hover')) {
            dropDownTrigger.classList.remove("active");
        }
    });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.path (array) to see if the path contains your menu and stop the event.

For browsers not supporting path, iterate over the parents until reaches body or stop when it equals the target.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath

Answer (score 0):

You have completed almost 99%. You just have to invoke the clickOutSide function inside your dropdowntrigger.

```
    var dropDownContent = document.querySelector(".drop-down-content");
    var dropDownTrigger = document.querySelector(".drop-down");

    dropDownTrigger.onclick = function () {
        dropDownTrigger.classList.toggle("active");
        clickedOutside(e); // this line will solve your problem
    };
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', clickedOutside);

    function clickedOutside(e) {
        if (e.target != dropDownContent &&
            e.target.parentNode != dropDownContent) {
            dropDownTrigger.classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
```

If you are going to add different logic for a menu item click, you should write a separate function. for instance

```
   dropDownTrigger.onclick = function () {
        dropDownTrigger.classList.toggle("active");
        closeMenuDropDown(e); // this line will solve your problem
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', clickedOutside);
   };

   function closeMenuDropDown() {
       dropDownTrigger.classList.remove("active");
   }
```

Hope It solves your problem.